"Annotation not applicable to this kind of reference" error for Valid annotation with class name with the package
This code is working:
public class Foo {

    private List<@Valid String> bar = Collections.emptyList();
}

But this one is not:
public class Foo {

    private List<@Valid java.lang.String> bar = Collections.emptyList();
}

The error message in my IDE is:

Annotation not applicable to this kind of reference

also I've noticed that import to List becomes unused:


"The error message in my IDE" Not clear whether you mean "a warning displayed by my IDE" or "an error produced by the Java compiler".

@valid annotation will not work on primitive type like String, int . Did you try with some class ?

@Knight71 yes, I tried - result is the same

@Olivier I suppose - both of them

The error message seems fairly clear: llegally placed annotation: type annotations must directly precede  the simple name of the type they are meant to affect (or the [] for arrays)

This would be covered under the "Where Annotations May Appear" chapter in the Java Language Specification, see here.
The chapter states

A type annotation is admissible if both of the following are true:

The simple name to which the annotation is closest is classified as a TypeName, not a PackageName.
If the simple name to which the annotation is closest is followed by "." and another TypeName - that is, the annotation appears as @Foo T.U - then U denotes an inner class of T.


and later goes on to say

It is a compile-time error if an annotation of interface A applies to a type (or any part of a type) in a type context, and A is applicable in type contexts, but the annotation is not admissible.

and gives an example that is equivalent to yours

For example, assume an annotation interface TA which is meta-annotated with just @Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE). The terms @TA java.lang.Object and java.@TA lang.Object are illegal because the simple name to which @TA is closest is classified as a package name. On the other hand, java.lang.@TA Object is legal.

So you could move the annotation to after the package name prefix and it would compile (so you could continue using a fully qualified name, if it was necessary to do so)
private List<java.lang.@Valid Integer> bar = Collections.emptyList();

Here's another example, simply to highlight this isn't strictly related to your use of the annotation on a type used as a generic type argument (if that was a concern)
@Target(value = ElementType.TYPE_USE)
@interface ExampleAnnotation {} // similar to @Valid
class OkExample extends @ExampleAnnotation Observable {
    @ExampleAnnotation public static String ok;
    @ExampleAnnotation public static java.lang.String bad; // same error
}
class BadExample extends @ExampleAnnotation java.util.Observable {} // same error


Thank you!
But how to fix this example:
@Target(value = ElementType.TYPE_USE) @interface ExampleAnnotation {} // similar to @Valid class OkExample extends @ExampleAnnotation Observable {     @ExampleAnnotation public static String ok;     @ExampleAnnotation public static java.lang.String bad; // same error } 
?

@Target(value = ElementType.TYPE_USE) @interface ExampleAnnotation {} // similar to @Valid class OkExample extends @ExampleAnnotation Observable {     @ExampleAnnotation public static String ok;     java.lang.@ExampleAnnotation public static String bad; // same error } 
This also doesn't work

@gstackoverflow You're not annotating a type with that example, you're annotating a field. But the annotation doesn't have a @Target value for FIELD.

didn't get you. Let's imagine that second field has a type String but from my custom package. How could I annotate it?

@gstackoverflow The example in your question and the example in your comment are two different things. The annotation in your question annotates a type. The annotation in your comment annotates a field (declaration). ExampleAnnotation needs to be annotated with @Target(value = ElementType.FIELD) for that to work.

@Target(value = ElementType.TYPE_USE) @interface ExampleAnnotation {} // similar to @Valid @Target(value = ElementType.FIELD) @interface AnotherAnnotation {} // similar to @Valid class OkExample extends @ExampleAnnotation Observable {     @ExampleAnnotation public static String ok;     java.lang.@AnotherAnnotation public static String bad; // same error } 
@Sotirios this one also doesn't work

@gstackoverflow It's not clear what you're trying to do anymore. What are you thinking with java.lang.@AnotherAnnotation? That's valid if you were annotating the type String, not the bad field. And it would only work if AnotherAnnotation had a target value of TYPE_USE.
